# Error while trying to inherit from a class derived from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have developed a class called `BaseVC` by subclassing `UIViewController` class. When I try to inherit from my new `BaseVC` class I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_BaseVC", referenced from:
_OBJC_METACLASS_$_ClassX in ClassX.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BaseVC", referenced from:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassX in ClassX.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I try to do it in a small test app everything is OK.

Comment: did you add the BaseVC.m Class to your target?

Comment: Solved it... I forgot to include my new class in all project targets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your **BaseVC.m** in your `Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources` . This should do the trick.

Comment: Thx alot, as soon as I wrote this issue it hit me - hmmm i have 10 targets :)